# How do I copy a mounted dmg's files to another location using a unix terminal?

Tags: macos, bash, unix, dmg

I am making a bash script that will automatically download and install Google Chrome to a user's applications folder on a MacBook Pro running OSX 10.7. I am able to successfully download and mount the .dmg file from Google's servers, but I am unable to grab the actual Google Chrome.app file from the mounted dmg. Here is what I have written:

```
#Download and Install Google Chrome browser

DMG='/mactest/googlechrome.dmg'
USER="Mac"

curl https://dl.google.com/chrome/mac/stable/GGRO/googlechrome.dmg > $DMG

hdiutil attach $DMG

cp -r '/Volumes/Google Chrome/*' '/Users/$USER/Applications'

hdiutil unmount '/Volumes/Google Chrome'
rm $DMG
```

upon running this script everything runs as intended except for this error:

```
cp: /Volumes/Google Chrome/*: No such file or directory
```

any ideas?

Comment: use double quotes " instead of single ' so the shell will expand the * for you

Answer (score 2):

Your error is because there isn't a file named * inside that folder. The single quotes are preventing the shell from evaluating * to find matching filenames. Try one of these instead:

```
cp -r '/Volumes/Google Chrome/Google Chrome.app' /Users/$USER/Applications

cp -r /Volumes/Google\ Chrome/Google\ Chrome.app /Users/$USER/Applications
```